# Is there anyway to create a git project in Team foundation server?

Tags: git, tfs

I know that in Team Foundation Service (https://somename.visualstudio.com, not Team Foundation Server) allow user can create a Git project integrate with work item, task and so on.
But I'm going to install my own Team Foundation Server on local, but using Git as version controlling. I would like to integrate git master branch with my Work Item, Task, but my developer can edit and commit changes, then I can view which code was changed and related to some items as well as TFService do.
Please give some suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Git functionality that you see in TF Service has been added to the on-premise TFS in the TFS 2013 version.  You can download and install the TFS 2013 RC today, the RTM version should be released in the next couple of weeks.

Comment: You can install the RC version and easily upgrade once the RTM arrives.

Comment: So, you mean that only available on the TFS 2013 RC or later version ?

Comment: Correct, the TF Service (Cloud), is generally about 3 months ahead of on-premise TFS in terms of features (in the case of Git it was significantly farther ahead until now).

Comment: I totally agree with you. Thanks. By the way, is there any tool to do git clone or commit a TFS project relate to some working item on my local TFS server?

Comment: I'm not really experienced with git yet, so not sure if this answers your question, but when you do a commit in TFS Git repository, you can specify a WI # in the commit comment and TFS will automatically link that commit and the Work Item.  This blog post has more info: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/01/30/getting-started-with-git-in-visual-studio-and-team-foundation-service.aspx

Comment: I think that available on TFS 2103, not for 2012. I'm using TFS 2012 and I found that I can use http://git-tfs.com to checkin my git. Thanks again.